# Hooking into Forms redrawing

Tags: winforms, hook, paint

I'm looking for a way to overlay the graphical output of a third-party application with some lines, arcs etc. The applications accepts a handle of a window in which it will then display its output.

Using VC++ I put together a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio that draws (non-static) stuff in the onPaint-method of a form. Passing this form's handle to the other app, of course, overwrites my graphics stuff every time the other app redraws.

Can I somehow hook into this redrawing process to add my graphics *after* the other app redraws? Overlaying the form with a transparent panel onto which I draw could be an alternative. But *real* transparency for controls seem to be a problem of its own in Windows ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this easily without getting notifications from the app.  Which, if it doesn't provide them, would require setting a global hook with SetWindowsHookEx() so you can see the WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT messages.  That's hard to get right, you cannot write such a hook in managed code.  Since it requires injecting a DLL into the target process.

The only other option is that you put a transparent overlay on top of your form.  Another form that has its TransparencyKey property set.  The basic code you need to get that right is available in my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/).  You just need to tweak it so it is permanent.